# Match url with numbers 1-50 and ignore anything greater

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match URLs that have any number 1-50 but exclude any other numbers like 51, 150, 5000, 1000 etc. as well as expressions like "30K".

Right now I have:

```
([2-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)
```

But it pulls in all the additional numbers I mentioned (1000, 30K, 150, etc).

Any help appreciated! I'm new to RegEx.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the urls which you are trying to match? Try using a word boundary `\b`

Comment: You probably need `(?<!\d)(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)(?!\d)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\b` for word boundary:

```
\b(?:[1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)\b
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/IQKVK2/3